# Python virtual environment is not activating in centOS

Tags: django-2.2, python-3.8

I am trying to install django in CentOS 7 cloud server. For that I have installed Virtual environment by using `python -m venv env`. And environment installed successfully, but it is not activating when I used the shell command `source env/bin/activate`. The name of the current virtual environment is NOT appear on the left of the prompt. So I understand virtual environment is not active. My commands in terminal given below.

```
user@libserver.libsoft.in /$ python3.8 -V
Python 3.8.0    

user@libserver.libsoft.in /$ which python3.8
/usr/local/bin/python3.8    

user@libserver.libsoft.in /$ python3.8 -m venv /home/LPython/my_env

user@libserver.libsoft.in /$ cd /home/LPython/my_env

user@libserver.libsoft.in /home/LPython/my_env$ source bin/activate
```

I created my_env in /home/LPython/. Any problem with this path?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. Actually I was not using **BASH shell**, even if the **echo $SHELL** outputs **bin/bash**. Because of this output, I thought i was using using BASH shell. Then I login through **SSH**. If you are using Windows must login through **PUTTY**. Then I could activate my virtual environment through `source my_env/bin/activate`